# How to get 'heading' info from GPS on an iPhone WebApp

Tags: javascript, iphone, gps

I am making a mobile webapp for iPhone and probably other devices and am able to get the lat/long with a reasonable accuracy but I'm not getting any other values from the phone's GPS. The 'heading' is quite important for what I'm wanting to do. Is there a way for Mobile Safari to give this info or is it not supported yet? I haven't found any information about how much of the W3C Geolocation API spec is supported by the iPhone.

I have tried a few libraries but haven't found them to give more functionality to the iPhone. I'm using:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(on_success, on_failure, options);
```

The watch position works better than `getCurrentPosition` seemingly because the GPS doesn't give a good reading when only called once. With `watchPosition`, the position is updated as it gets more accurate then I clear it when it's an acceptable value. I've tested with iPhone 4 and iPhone 3GS both with iOS 4.0.2.
altitude, altitudeAccuracy, heading, speed all come back `null`. Parameters like enableHighAccuracy and a longer responseTime or timeout did not have any effect.

Any insight, even if that it is definitively not supported, would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I leave this here because I wasted a full day with the same problem.
You are looking into the wrong API for getting the Orientation of the phone. The heading attribute in the geolocation is not the compas orientation but a direction calculated based on the movement of the phone. So if you are standing still heading is null. As soon you as you are moving the heading points into the direction of your movement. See this docu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

What you are looking for is the "deviceorientation" event. For iOS/Safari you have to manually request the feature first.
(This is Typescript code)

```html
const isIOS = !(
    navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) &&
    navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
);
if (isIOS) {
    (DeviceOrientationEvent as any).requestPermission()
        .then((response: any) => {
            if (response === "granted") {
                window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
            } else {
                alert("has to be allowed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
} else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Geo Meter from Alex Gibson:
http://miniapps.co.uk/geometer/

He outputs heading in his webapp.

/Mogens

Answer (score 0):

Thanks /Morgens for your link, but Alex Gibson's script doesn't give access to the heading coords.

I just find this from apple which gives acces to.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceOrientationEventClassRef/DeviceOrientationEvent/DeviceOrientationEvent.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/DeviceOrientationEvent/initDeviceOrientationEvent